# How can I determine if an app was installed from a Facebook Ad?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, analytics

We have a multiplatform service and we give our users a 30 day trial. A user can sign up on iOS, use the web version and finally do the payment on Android... even if it's weird, its a possible. The database is shared between all platforms

We are using Facebook Ads to generate App installs but we don't know how to do the conversions' attribution properly. The main problem is that if, for example, a user install the app from a Facebook app but he end up paying from the web version we lost track that the origin of this user was the ad.

I would like to know if it's possible to determine using the Facebook SDK, on the first run of the app, if the user comes from a Facebook Ad and in that case I would store that information in our database to do the attribution once the purshase is done. Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

Regards!

Comment: You can't. Facebook give you aggregated data but you will never know who came from a Facebook ad

Comment: Are you sure WizKid? I am currently investigating how to do it with deep linking (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/deep-linking). If I make any improvemenet I'll post it here!